# Any nice way to clone a record in jquery-jtable?

Tags: jquery-jtable

My users will be adding records to a database using jtable (http://jTable.org). The 'Add Record' button works but all the cells are empty. I'd like them to be filled with the contents of the record we're cloning.

There are only four actions available: listAction, createAction, updateAction, deleteAction.
I suppose I'm looking for a cloneAction.

Anyone done this already?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a "nice way" to clone a record, if you mean built-in function.

May I interest you in reading up on [SelectingRows](http://www.jtable.org/Demo/SelectingRows) demo alongside with AddRecord programmatically? Check the API reference [here](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#met-addRecord) for adding records.

Comment: Since I'm trying to duplicate a record, how would I populate the 'addRecord' with the record I'm cloning? i.e. record: { Name: _what goes here?_ Thank you.

Comment: If you only have one selected row, you may try:

var $selectedRows = $('#YOURTABLE').jtable('selectedRows');
$selectedRows.each(function () {
    var record = $(this).data('record');
    // Create an instance of the object you're working with, like

});

function CreateObject()
{

Comment: LOL I can't edit that comment after 5 minutes it has been posted. That sucks. Well...

You put the selected record there, like:

var record = $('#YOURTABLE').jtable('selectedRows').eq(0);

Or you can loop through all the selected records and add them all, something like:

$('#YOURTABLE').jtable('selectedRows').each(function()
{
    // add programatically here
});